# Why isn't FileStreamResult (and possibly ActionResult) IDisposable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The `FileStreamResult` class owns an `IDisposable` stream if instantiated from a Controller with the constructor that takes a `Stream` argument:

```
public FileResult MyController()
{
    ...
    Stream stream = ...
    return File(stream, "text/plain", fileName);
}
```

Surely it (and probably its base class `ActionResult`) should therefore implement `IDisposable`?

Of course, if all goes well, `FileStreamResult.WriteFile()` method will dispose the `Stream`.  And when using the built-in Action Invoker `ControllerActionInvoker`, there doesn't seem to be much risk of an Exception being thrown before this happens.

But given the extensible architecture of MVC, it seems to me that there is the potential for situations where an `Exception` would prevent the Stream being disposed when using a custom Action Invoker.

I would have thought that `ActionResult` ought to implement `IDisposable`, and Action Invokers should be required  to guarantee they are disposed.

Is this a design flaw or is there a good reason for this?

**UPDATE**

From Henk Holterman's answer:

> Note that the Action Invoker couldn't close the file either, it would be to soon.

I don't understand what you're saying here - probably because I don't know enough about the handler framework.  As far as I can see, the Stream is currently disposed as follows by the built-in Action Invoker:

InvokeAction => InvokeActionResult => ActionResult.ExecuteResult => FileStreamResult.WriteFile

So why can't InvokeAction use a try/finally block to ensure an `IDisposable` ActionResult would be disposed - conceptually (and probably oversimplified) something like:

```
bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
{
    ...
    ActionResult actionResult;

    try
    {
        ...
        actionResult = ... call Action method
        ...
        actionResult.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (actionResult != null) actionResult.Dispose();
    }
}
```